# IDE for front-end development with auto-completion

Tags: javascript, html, css, autocomplete, ide

i am looking for IDE with decent auto completion for html,css,javascript.
i have found Atom(text editor) very convenient.
and it not only does auto-complete but also shows all the option.
for example, if i type "backgro", it shows up all background property as selections such as background-color,background-width.

i want to find IDE like this.
would you please recommend some??
thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use visual studio code.
There are some Extensions as well which you will find helpful like Git etc..
Moreover visual studio code is light weight and open source.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sublime text and emmet plugin even though emmet is a plugin that helps you to write html and css much faster and easier!

And as for an IDE, in my opinion Visual studio is one of the best there!

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans has an auto-completion feature. You can download it here: https://netbeans.org/downloads/